# addInterceptor intercept NullPointException. in Retrofit2

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, retrofit2.6

I got this error:

```
Fatal Exception: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
com.example.manager.helper.my_api.MyServiceGenerator$createService$$inlined$-addInterceptor$1.intercept (Interceptor.kt:81)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp (RealCall.kt:197)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run (RealCall.kt:502)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

And I have no idea why it caused.

What I implemented is:

```
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { // If Build is Debug Mode, Show Log
            logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY // Logs request and response lines and their respective headers and bodies (if present).
        } else { // Otherwise, show nothing.
            logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE // No logs
        }

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        client.addInterceptor {
            val original = it.request()

            val request = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("User-Agent", MyApp.httpUserAgent!!)
                    .build()

            it.proceed(request)
        }

        client.addInterceptor(logging)
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .callTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Comment: `Interceptor.kt` line 81. Guesssing it's the `MyApp.httpUserAgent!!` that throws if you're trying to convert a null to a nonnull type with `!!`

Comment: @c-an please add code of your HttpLoggingInterceptor and mark like 81.

Answer (score 0):

You are not finished building of your client. That's why it's null. In general you forgot to call build() method.

That's how it have to be implemented.

```
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .callTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. That would cause a compilation error , as `client` would be an object with type `OkHttpClient.Builder`instead of `OkHttpClient`, so the OP wouldn't be able to call methods like `client.newCall(...)`

Comment: @user2340612 hm... you are right. I was missing kotlin specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `!!` in your codes you should use it with a null check. Like this

```
if(MyApp.httpUserAgent != null) {
    val request = original.newBuilder()
                          .header("User-Agent", MyApp.httpUserAgent!!)
                          .build()
else {
    //here do something in case of null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when upgrade logging-interceptor from 3.10.0 to 4.7.2

Debug find cause is ssl factory

```
// old code
builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
```

change the code to new code

```
// new code
builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, x509TrustManager)
```